# Java SimpleDateFormat not throwing ParseException

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(df.parse("32/12/2016"));
System.out.println(df.parse("30/02/2017"));
System.out.println(df.parse("31/11/2016"));
```

I'm expecting all the above scenarios as `ParseException` but but I'm getting output as below:

> Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017
>
> Thu Mar 02 00:00:00 GMT 2017
>
> Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2016

In my case all the above scenarios are validation failed one.

**Note:** I can't do equals(post and pre parse the date.) also why because my date inputs may come as DD/MM/YYYY or D/M/YY.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: May I ask what is the situation in your app where you would normally be expecting a date such as February 30?  One alternative might be to use Java 8's date API.

Comment: If user send date by mistake i need to send response back saying invalid date. so he can send 28/29 of feb month date.

Comment: Try to add this line 

     df.setLenient(false);

it throws exception exception after adding this line.
Without this it adds the days to next cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `df.setLenient(false);` to make it verify that the dates are valid.

Comment: excellent this is what I'm expecting.